# Android MediaCodec instances

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Can Android devices reliably perform video decoding-encoding with MediaCodec?

I made an Encode Decode system, that is capable to concatenate videos together at 1080p. It uses two MediaCodec instances at the same time, with a GLES surface in between (to allow easier input codec swapping and add some effects).

I tested on different >API21 devices. All tests were performed with videos produced by same device, with same codec configurations (therefore all tests where performed with video codecs that are supported - all were encoded with h.264).

It works well on many devices, but:

- on some devices encoding artifacts are present after the "stitching point". Frame analysis of the output video shows errors in the PTS close to the stitching point (much longer or shorter frame times). Those artifacts are probably caused by the player decoding a badly encoded video (being the PST errors present)
- on few devices the produced video is technically perfect (no errors in present in frames or in encoding) but the video itself is completely wrong, containing only corrupted frames (and sometimes partially cropped screen). Here it looks like the decoding (while Decoding-Encoding) the video was not successful.

No errors are shown, nor logs are shown in any case. All the devices were perfectly capable of encoding the initial videos and all the devices are capable of playing those videos. But it looks like those devices are not capable of handling encoding & decoding at the same time.

Is this possible? May MediaCodec be so implemented that will neither throw an exception if the underlaying architecture is performing a task it is unable to carry out successfully?

Comment: Just for clarification, you mean `h.264` instead of  `x264` and `PTS` instead of `PST`. There are devices that cannot handle two `MediaCodec` instances with 1080p (e.g. low tier Samsung devices like j5) but they usually bug out beforehand. And just to check, are you adjusting the PTS correctly? The encoder doesn't usually do it for you. Also have you checkt the timeline for correctness?

Comment: Yes, made those corrections. Thankyou. By adjusting the PTS correctly you mean shifting the catenated video time (yes), the first PTS in the exported video to be 0 (allmost, it depends whether there is a audio frame slightly earlyer, then this would be the 0) or whether i adjust the original video slightly variable framerate (no).

Comment: In the first mentioned case (smaller artefacts) in the timeline (if you mean the frametime) there are some smaller glitches on the "stitching point" but they are induced by the Encoding MediaCodec, being the input PTS to that perfect. In the second case the frame time & PTS are ok, but the video is completely corrupted (by this i mean, data is perfect, no frames are lost during playback, but each frame contains a corrupted image).